# social in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I want to add Social solution (Newsfeed Posting and Replying).
In the out of the box , we need an app SharePoint, but in the coded way I dont khow how to proceed. Do I need to recode the app or, to have the wsp solution?

Comment: You found an app? What do you mean? You question is not clear. Add details please

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822974(v=office.15).aspx#bkmk_PubPosts1

I must Create and delete posts and retrieve the social feed by using the JavaScript object model in SharePoint 2013